# How can I submit a form using an image in php

Tags: php, forms, imagebutton, isset

I want to submit a form to the database and I want to use a sprite image instead of regular submit buttons..
Here is the images I'm using

```
<div class="cancel">
    <a href="#" id='cancel_btn' name=''><img src="../images/img_trans.gif"></a>
</div>

<div class="save_and_new">
    <a href="#" id='save_and_new_btn' name=''><img src="../images/img_trans.gif"></a>
</div>

<div class="save_and_quit">
    <a href="#" id='save_and_quit_btn' name=''><img src="../images/img_trans.gif"></a>
</div>

if(isset(......)){

}
```

I have no idea what to put in the isset function ...
Do i need to set names to the images? or what?

Comment: you could use javascript's `form.submit()`

Comment: How to do that? I'm still a newbie :\

Answer (score 4):

You could just use

```
<input type="image src="/your/button/image/here.gif" />
```

instead of the images nested inside anchors.

The only problem would be that you can't directly sense which button exactly was pressed because `<input type="image" />` does not post a value. If you really need multiple post buttons that also post a value:

```
<button name="button" value="action1"><img src="/your/image/here.gif" alt="action 1" /></button>
<button name="button" value="action2"><img src="/your/image/here.gif" alt="action 2" /></button>
```

Comment: Note that if you give the `type="image"` input a name, you will get x and y coordinates of click on the pressed button in `$_REQUEST` (whatever the OP uses...)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in Jquery. Try this,

```
$("#save_and_new_btn").click(function() {

     $("#form").submit();

});
```

`#form` is id of form

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a form is submitted when the user presses a submit button. However, sometimes, you may need to submit the form programmatically using JavaScript.

JavaScript provides the form object that contains the submit() method. Use the ‘id’ of the form to get the form object.

For example, if the name of your form is ‘myform’, the JavaScript code for the submit call is:

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

But, how to identify a form? Give an id attribute in the form tag

```
<form id='myform' action='formmail.pl'>
```

Here is the code to submit a form when a hyperlink is clicked:

```
<form name="myform" action="handle-data.php">
Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
<a href="javascript: submitform()">Search</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

Source: [How to Submit a Form Using JavaScript](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml)

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and gives you my feedback about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript.

Find a form which has to be submitted. Then add actions to each  elements. Whene they're clicked you are submitting (or canceling) form.